# Using $stateProvider in Angularjs for different server side route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I planned to add an admin panel which use a different layout template for angularjs and expressjs.

For example, the mean stack now defined to use $stateProvider as route but it will work globally.

```
    $stateProvider.state('access home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html'
    })
```

That means when I call localhost/#/home and localhost/admin/#/home would get the same template url.

But what I want is that the route and admin panel route should not have such conflict and render differently for even the same route.

I am new to use angularjs and please give a help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do not change url to `/admin/home` for admin route.

Comment: because I don't want to use the same main navigation with the main site and the template content will render inside the ui-view directive . any suggestion for a better way